# Pass a callback to GreenSock when done with animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gsap

After I searched a lot for a awnser to my question, I didn't find it.

So, my question is:

I'm doing a website and in the first page, I have a 'hand' image moving to the company 'logo'. After that, the image of the company logo moves, but only after the first move is completed.

My code is:

```
function hand() {
    var hand = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .hand", 2.5, 
    {top: -300, left: -400, rotation: 10},  
    {top: -300, rotation: 40, left: -300});
}
```

Here the hand go to that position using the TweenMax library.

And the other function is:

```
function bolas(){
    $('.bolinhas').css({display:'block'});

    var bolinha1 = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .bolinha1", 5.5, 
    {top: 150, left: -100}, 
    {top: 650,  left: 100});

    var bolinha2 = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .bolinha2", 5.5, 
    {top: 150, left: -50}, 
    {top: 680,  left: -200});

    var bolinha3 = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .bolinha3", 5.5, 
    {top: 100, left: -80}, 
    {top: 680,  left: 290});

    var bolinha4 = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .bolinha4", 5.5, 
    {top: 80, left: -110}, 
    {top: 680,  left: -250} );

    var bolinha5 = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .bolinha5", 5.5, 
    {top: 100, left: -15,}, 
    {top: 650,  left: -70});

    var bolinha6 = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .bolinha6", 5.5, 
    {top: 150, left: -20}, 
    {top: 680,  left: 250});

    var bolinha7 = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .bolinha7", 5.5, 
    {top: -50, left: -10}, 
    {top: 650,  left: -70});

    var bolinha8 = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .bolinha8", 5.5, 
    {top: -150, left: -160}, 
    {top: 680,  left: -350});

    var bolinha9 = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .bolinha9", 5.5, 
    {top: -150, left: 10}, 
    {top: 680,  left: 70});
}
```

Using the same library, they make this movement, but at the same time.

How can I make a call back off the second function into the first one?

Comment: @Jamiec https://greensock.com/tweenmax

Answer (score 1):

try to use `onComplete` :

```
var bolinha1 = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .bolinha1", 5.5, 
{top: 150, left: -100}, 
{top: 650,  left: 100},
{onComplete:complete});

var complete = function () {
    //do something
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this-

1. You can simply use the `onComplete` callback inside the `fromTo` function like below-

   ```
   var hand = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .hand", 2.5, 
                   {top: -300, left: -400, rotation: 10},  
                   {top: -300, rotation: 40, left: -300}, 
                   {onComplete: bolas});
   ```
2. You can use the `eventCallback()` function from the TweenMax library. From the TweenMax documentation, here is what `eventCallback()` does-

   > Gets or sets an event callback like "onComplete", "onUpdate", "onStart", "onReverseComplete" or "onRepeat" (onRepeat only applies to TweenMax or TimelineMax instances) along with any parameters that should be passed to that callback.

   In your case, you can simply achieve the result by doing this-

   ```
   function hand() {
       var hand = TweenMax.fromTo(".start .hand", 2.5, 
                       {top: -300, left: -400, rotation: 10},  
                       {top: -300, rotation: 40, left: -300});
       hand.eventCallback("onComplete", bolas);
   }
   ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're utilizing the GreenSock library for this, you should create a `TimelineLite` [of your animations](http://greensock.com/timelinelite), some pseudo code as an explanation:

```
//instantiate a TimelineLite    
var tl = new TimelineLite();

//add a from() tween at the beginning of the timline
tl.from(head, 0.5, {left:100, opacity:0});

//add another tween immediately after
tl.from(subhead, 0.5, {left:-100, opacity:0});

//use position parameter "+=0.5" to schedule next tween 0.5 seconds after previous tweens end
tl.from(feature, 0.5, {scale:.5, autoAlpha:0}, "+=0.5");

//use position parameter "-=0.5" to schedule next tween 0.25 seconds before previous tweens end.
//great for overlapping
tl.from(description, 0.5, {left:100, autoAlpha:0}, "-=0.25");
```

It's easy to give a callback to this code, you can simply pass a function inside the new `var tl;` which would look like:

`var tl = new TimelineLite({onComplete: functionX()});`

Where functionX is the function you wish to execute as callback.